# what does "*firefoxproxy" or "*iexploreproxy" do

Tags: selenium

I am researching the selenium and I don't understand "*firefoxproxy" does for ? I can use selenium well with just "*firefox". Please explain to me when we will use that mode ?

Answer (score 0):

From the Selenium documentation:

"...additional run modes of *iexploreproxy and *firefoxproxy. These are provided for backwards compatibility only, and should not be used unless required by legacy test programs. Their use will present limitations with security certificate handling and with the running of multiple windows if your application opens additional browser windows."

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html

So just stick with *firefox.